# I have free'd dynamically allocated memory, but I am still getting memory leaks

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind

I am currently doing an assignment in C, and I have dynamically allocated my structs, linkedlist, and also a 2d array. At the end of the code I have also free'd these. I cannot show all of my code, due to it being an assignment which might be a bit harder to view the problem. I can provide snippets of the code though.

Below is my insertStart for my linkedlist

```
void insertStart(LinkedList* list, void* entry)
{
    Position* temp;
    void* newEntry = malloc(sizeof(Position));
    ListNode* newNd = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    temp = (Position*)entry;
    memcpy(newEntry, entry, sizeof(Position));

    newNd->data = newEntry;
    newNd->next = list->head;
    list->head = newNd;

    list->size++;
}
```

In this method, I have malloc'd the newNd, but I am unable to free, as it will result in a segmentation fault.

I have tried to use valgrind to check for memory leaks and this is what I get.

```
==1906==
==1906== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1906==     in use at exit: 1,332 bytes in 40 blocks
==1906==   total heap usage: 72 allocs, 32 frees, 14,676 bytes allocated
==1906==
==1906== 60 bytes in 3 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 10
==1906==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1906==    by 0x10AA1B: insertStart (linkedList.c:23)
==1906==    by 0x1099DA: controls (game.c:141)
==1906==    by 0x109596: game (game.c:44)
==1906==    by 0x109455: main (main.c:59)
==1906==
==1906== 60 bytes in 3 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 2 of 10
==1906==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1906==    by 0x10AA1B: insertStart (linkedList.c:23)
==1906==    by 0x109811: controls (game.c:111)
==1906==    by 0x109596: game (game.c:44)
==1906==    by 0x109455: main (main.c:59)
==1906==
==1906== 72 bytes in 3 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 3 of 10
==1906==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1906==    by 0x10AA29: insertStart (linkedList.c:24)
==1906==    by 0x1099DA: controls (game.c:141)
==1906==    by 0x109596: game (game.c:44)
==1906==    by 0x109455: main (main.c:59)
==1906==
==1906== 72 bytes in 3 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 4 of 10
==1906==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1906==    by 0x10AA29: insertStart (linkedList.c:24)
==1906==    by 0x109811: controls (game.c:111)
==1906==    by 0x109596: game (game.c:44)
==1906==    by 0x109455: main (main.c:59)
==1906==
==1906== 120 bytes in 6 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 5 of 10
==1906==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1906==    by 0x10AA1B: insertStart (linkedList.c:23)
==1906==    by 0x1098F8: controls (game.c:126)
==1906==    by 0x109596: game (game.c:44)
==1906==    by 0x109455: main (main.c:59)
==1906==
==1906== 140 bytes in 7 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 6 of 10
==1906==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1906==    by 0x10AA1B: insertStart (linkedList.c:23)
==1906==    by 0x109AC1: controls (game.c:156)
==1906==    by 0x109596: game (game.c:44)
==1906==    by 0x109455: main (main.c:59)
==1906==
==1906== 144 bytes in 6 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 7 of 10
==1906==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1906==    by 0x10AA29: insertStart (linkedList.c:24)
==1906==    by 0x1098F8: controls (game.c:126)
==1906==    by 0x109596: game (game.c:44)
==1906==    by 0x109455: main (main.c:59)
==1906==
==1906== 168 bytes in 7 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 8 of 10
==1906==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1906==    by 0x10AA29: insertStart (linkedList.c:24)
==1906==    by 0x109AC1: controls (game.c:156)
==1906==    by 0x109596: game (game.c:44)
==1906==    by 0x109455: main (main.c:59)
==1906==
==1906== 472 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 9 of 10
==1906==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1906==    by 0x48DF64D: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==1906==    by 0x48DF64D: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:86)
==1906==    by 0x109347: main (main.c:26)
==1906==
==1906== 860 (24 direct, 836 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 10 of 10
==1906==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1906==    by 0x10A9D1: createLinkedList (linkedList.c:11)
==1906==    by 0x1094DC: game (game.c:30)
==1906==    by 0x109455: main (main.c:59)
==1906==
==1906== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1906==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==1906==    indirectly lost: 836 bytes in 38 blocks
==1906==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1906==    still reachable: 472 bytes in 1 blocks
==1906==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1906==
==1906== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==1906== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

If more of my code is needed, please let me know and I will see how much I can provide, thanks!

Comment: `loc = findLoc('P', arr, row, col);`, for instance, reassigns the pointer that had been `malloc()`'d... This cannot be healthy... Too little code to say more... (Same for pointer `carloc`...)

Comment: Ok thanks. I have just changed the method to pass in loc, instead of returning it. This has fixed some of the memory leaks, but I am still trying to figure out the rest.

Comment: Not keen on trying to perform "keyhole diagnosis/surgery". For future reference, please do not change your question in such a way as to invalidate comments/answers you've received. If you have a separate question about another block of code, please post a new question.

Comment: Ok will do for the next time, thanks for the feedback

Comment: What is _temp_ used for in your code? You don't do anything about it.

Comment: I did use it previously to test if the data was correct by printing it out.

Comment: How do you deallocate your linked lists?